# Compilation issues on a shared project (Qt)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, shared-folders, c++, qt

I'm working on an already existing project. So the project folders and files are located in a shared folder (read, write and execute permission for everyone) on the development PC. The project runs perfectly on the proprietary session (as in the session in which it was originally developed), but as I try to compile on my session it just don't work. When I try to open it, it says that the .user file wasn't found for the current project and even after configure the whole project I always get several compilation errors (it goes from non recognition of libraries to non recognition of ui_.h files). If there is a solution that any of you know so I can export or open the project on my session properly it would be nice.

Thanks for any help you could give me!